# Invalid bitfield flag or number

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot but when I did some code and ran it this error pops up:

```
index.js

const discord = require('discord.js')
const { token } = require('./config.json')
const Client = new discord.Client({
    intents: [discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_BANS, discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS, discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INTEGRATIONS, discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_WEBHOOKS, discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INVITES, discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES, discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES, discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING, discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTION, discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING]
})

Client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`${Client.user.tag} is online!`)
})

Client.login(token)




config.json
{
  "token": "my_token"
}
```

When I run the code I get this error

```
C:\Users\krisz\OneDrive\Desktop\TalkBot 2.9.56 Beta\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:152
    throw new RangeError('BITFIELD_INVALID', bit);
    ^

RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: undefined.
    at Function.resolve (C:\Users\krisz\OneDrive\Desktop\TalkBot 2.9.56 Beta\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:152:11)
    at C:\Users\krisz\OneDrive\Desktop\TalkBot 2.9.56 Beta\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:147:54
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.resolve (C:\Users\krisz\OneDrive\Desktop\TalkBot 2.9.56 Beta\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:147:40)
    at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\krisz\OneDrive\Desktop\TalkBot 2.9.56 Beta\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:546:33)
    at new Client (C:\Users\krisz\OneDrive\Desktop\TalkBot 2.9.56 Beta\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:73:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\krisz\OneDrive\Desktop\TalkBot 2.9.56 Beta\index.js:3:16)    
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'BITFIELD_INVALID'
}
```

How can I fix this issue?
I am using Discord.js V13
Node.js 16.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small Typo: `DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTION` -> `DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` on line 4 of index.js.

That's probably why node is freaking out about an invalid bitfield flag; `discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTION` is `undefined` (a.k.a it doesn't exist).